# Simplifying Exponents with Radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've been working on this problem and so far I'm stump on it, can someone help me solve this problem, my high school teacher has already cover this topic before but due to some issues, I was not available to attend his class. Thanks in Advance!

> Simplify  $\dfrac{x^3x^{-2}}{x^{5/2}\sqrt{x^9}}$. Your answer must have no negative exponents.

Comment: This is just repeated use of the following rules: $x^a x^b=x^{a+b}$, $\frac{x^a}{x^b}=x^{a-b}$ and $(x^a)^b =x^{a b}$ for real numbers $a,b$. Recall also that $\sqrt{x}=x^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$a^m\cdot a^n=a^{n+m}$ and $\sqrt(x^m)=x^{\frac{m}{2}}$